How to set individual columns in the siunitx package to boldface? It it a bug?
I want to make individual cells in a table (the best performing ones) in bold face. Therefore I finally would need an \ifstrequal or \IfStrEq statement in the future. However, I failed way earlier. More specifically, I failed by just setting a single column to boldface. Here is what I tried. For some reason the \bfseries moves to the next row in the csv file:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    l % Sampler
    S[table-format=1.1,round-mode=places]
}
\csvreader[
    head to column names,
    head to column names prefix = COL,
    late after line={\\},  % Add a line break after each row
  ]{results.csv}{}
  {%
    \COLvalue \COLsampler & \bf \COLvalue
  }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

results.csv:
sampler,value,best
BlackOutSampler,0.5286692501245963,notbest
GrayOutSampler,0.6661195535292708,best
BlurSampler,0.6098944242193235,notbest
MeanSampler,0.4525745571101138,notbest

This leads to this:

How can this be?

using tabularx with no X column cannot do anything useful, you would be better to use tabular here.

Ah yes. However, the same problem exists for tabular. I'll edit the question.

In order to be able to style the output of a siunitx command with something like \bfseries, you need to set mode=text, reset-text-series=false (plus reset-text-family and/or reset-text-shape if you want to change the family and/or the shape as well). See section 4.2 of the siunitx package manual.
Having done this, you can check the string stored in \COLbest and put a \bfseries if equal. Sadly, there is another problem that pops up if using a S column as last colum with csvsimple (it seems that this is also the core issue you have). To circumvent this, one way is not to use an S column, but the \tablenum command:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\sisetup{
    mode=text,
    reset-text-series=false,
    table-format=1.1, 
    round-mode=places
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq:nn { en } { T }
\cs_new:Npn \bfseriesifbest {
    \str_if_eq:enT { \COLbest } { best } {
        \bfseries
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{results.csv}
sampler,value,best
BlackOutSampler,0.5286692501245963,notbest
GrayOutSampler,0.6661195535292708,best
BlurSampler,0.6098944242193235,notbest
MeanSampler,0.4525745571101138,notbest
\end{filecontents}

\def\mystrbest{best}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    l % Sampler
    c
}
\csvreader[
    head to column names,
    head to column names prefix={COL},
    late after line={\\},  % Add a line break after each row
  ]{results.csv}{}
  {%
    \COLsampler & \bfseriesifbest\tablenum{\COLvalue}
  }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}




The problem arise because the last column is of type S. This is addressed is section 5.4 of the csvsimple-legacy manual, Tables with Number Formatting:

Special care is needed, if the first or the last column is to be formatted with the column type S. The number detection of siunitx is disturbed by the line reading code of csvsimple-legacy which actually is present at the first and last column. To avoid this problem, the content of the first and last column could be formatted not by the table format definition, but by using a suitable \tablenum formatting directly, see siunitx.
Another and very nifty workaround suggested by Enrico Gregorio is to add an invisible dummy column with c@{} as first column and @{}c as last column.

You need also to tell siunitx to accept bod face setup with  table-model-setup = \bfseries and text-series-to-math.
So, replace
\begin{tabular}{
    l % Sampler
    S[table-format=1.1,round-mode=places]
}

with
\begin{tabular}{
    l % Sampler
    S[table-format=1.1, round-mode=places, table-model-setup = \bfseries, text-series-to-math]
    @{}c
}

The string comparison can be done with
\ifcsvstrequal{\COLbest}{best}{\bfseries}{}

Full example:
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{results.csv}
sampler,value,best
BlackOutSampler,0.5286692501245963,notbest
GrayOutSampler,0.6661195535292708,best
BlurSampler,0.6098944242193235,notbest
MeanSampler,0.4525745571101138,notbest
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    l % Sampler
    S[table-format=1.1, round-mode=places, table-model-setup = \bfseries, text-series-to-math]
    @{}c
}
\csvreader[
    head to column names,
    head to column names prefix = COL,
    late after line={\\},  % Add a line break after each row
  ]{results.csv}{}
  {%
    \COLvalue \COLsampler &  \ifcsvstrequal{\COLbest}{best}{\bfseries}{} \COLvalue &
  }
\end{tabular}


\end{document}


By the way, csvsimple has a LaTeX3 version (csvsimple-l3), available with
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}

You should maybe consider to use it.
